# Recommendation for a research topic relating Algebra and other topics.

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

As part of a seminar in Algebra I'm doing a lecture, and I have the option to pick a subject.
I want to research a topic that is related to my points of interests, and wondering if you have some recommendations for a book, or a paper that combines methods in Algebra to topics in:

- Measure Theory
- Mathematical Logic or Model Theory

Or some other interesting, but fitting for an undergraduate course, topic in general analysis.

I've started researching some books in Algebraic Logic, and downloaded "The Mathematics of Metamathematics".

Comment: I suggest the topic of Haar measure: [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) is detailed enough to give you some ideas for your lecture.

Comment: @Crostul thank you! t

Comment: I am not a professor, nor professional, but I was searching a subject, there are two documents that seems interesting from those you could be inspired. My search was in Google for the words: *algebra, fractals, measure theory*, you get  Johannes Geißler, *Fractal sets and Preparation to Geometric Measure Theory* from Universität Kaiserslautern, and the second was searching the words *algebra, fractals*, then I found  *Fractals and Linear Algebra*, Goshem College MAA Indiana Spring Meeting 2004.  I have no idea if it is possible get inspiration from this to get a genuine lecture. Good luck.

Comment: @user243301 thank you! that looks really interesting!

Comment: Good luck and courage with your lecture. Fractals have and will have in the future, a lot of applications.